# Automatically save a jpg along with AI file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, save, file-format

In Photoshop we have "Save Extra JPEG" in Script Event Manager which saves a jpg automatically with the psd file.

Do we have something similar in Illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

Using Adobe's ExtendScript js library, you could certainly write something without much work. I don't remember the commands off hand but you would do the following.

1. Get the path to the document
2. Set the JPEG export settings
3. Export a JPEG to the path you saved
4. Execute a basic save command

Then you add that script to your scripts menu and give it a key sequence for easy use.

Comment: The API has an event kAIDocumentWritePostprocessNotifier that could be made to tie with normal save. So It is possible to do this even transparently. Unfortunately illustrator scripting engine does not expose events.

Comment: That's why I outlined the simple way around ;) Another option is to build a plug-in that makes it a doc level preference, but I didn't think that would be a helpful suggestion.

Comment: im not saying it is. Problem is the illustrator sctipting suite is very crippled. Illustrator  wont let you make a shortcut for a script without you needing to redo this every time you startup. So its not really easy to be nice in this regard with the script interface. Youd still need something to make it usable. Thats wy this is a comment.